# How to create button as a reset button for reset the form in angular8?

Tags: angular8

this is my code.how i use that in upload button?

```
resetForm() {
    this.formTemplate.reset();
    this.formTemplate.setValue({
      imageUrl: '',
      category: ''
    });
    this.imgSrc = '/assets/img/image.png';
    this.selectedImage = null;
    this.isSubmitted = false;
    this.currentUpload = null;
  }
```